# Can't manage to get the value of my formBuilder

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to make a form in Angular, with the possibility of adding products as I go and displaying them one after the other just below and finally, recovering everything when I validate the form.
Unfortunately when I add the line, its content is not retrieved.

Any ideas or solution ?

**HTML**

```
<form action="" [formGroup]="addRequest" class="container" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="demand-line">
    <div>
      <label for="requestTitle"> Nom de la demande d'achat </label>
      <input type="text" id="requestTitle" formControlName="requestTitle">
    </div>

    <div>
      <label> Degré d'urgence de la demande </label>
      <select formControlName="requestUrgency" required >
        <option> Normal</option>
        <option> Urgent</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="product-line">
    <div>
      <label for="productName"> Nom du produit</label>
      <input type="text" id="productName" name="productName"  formControlName="productName"  required>

    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="productQuantity"> Quantité</label>
      <input type="number" min="1" max="99" id="productQuantity" name="productQuantity" formControlName="productQuantity" required>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label for="productComment"> Remarque</label>
      <input type="text" id="productComment" name="productComment"  formControlName="productComment">
    </div>

    <div class="button">
      <button (click)="addLine()">
        <fa-icon class="icon"
                 [icon]="faPlus"
        ></fa-icon>
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="product-line product-line-added" *ngFor="let line of lines.controls; let i=index">
    <div>
      <label> {{ line.get('productName')?.value }}</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label> {{ line.get('productQuantity')?.value }}</label>
    </div>

    <div>
      <label> {{ line.get('productComment')?.value }}</label>
    </div>

    <div class="button">
      <button (click)="deleteLine(i)">
        <fa-icon class="icon"
                 [icon]="faTrash"
        ></fa-icon>
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="comment-container">
    <label for="generalComment"> Commentaire général</label>
    <textarea id="generalComment" name="generalComment" rows="5" formControlName="generalComment"></textarea>
  </div>

  <div class="button-container">
    <button class="btn-validate" type="submit"> Valider</button>
    <button class="btn-cancel" ><a routerLink="../"> Annuler</a></button>
  </div>
</form >
```

**My Model**

```
export class AddLineRequest {
  constructor(public productName: string, public productQuantity: string, public productComment: string) {
  }
}
```

**Component TS**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-add-purchase-request',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ShareModule, FaIconComponent, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, RouterLink],
  templateUrl: './form-add-purchase-request.component.html',
  styleUrl: './form-add-purchase-request.component.scss'
})

export class FormAddPurchaseRequestComponent {
  protected readonly faPlus = faPlus;
  protected readonly faTrash = faTrash;
  items: AddLineRequest[] = [];
  newProductName: string = '';
  newProductQuantity: string = '';
  newProductComment: string = '';
  submitted = false;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  addRequest = this.formBuilder.group({
    requestTitle: [''],
    requestUrgency: ['', Validators.required],
    lines: this.formBuilder.array([]),
    generalComment: ['']
  })

  get lines() {
    return this.addRequest.get('lines') as FormArray;
  }

  addLine() {
    // Accédez aux valeurs directement à partir du formulaire
    const productName = this.addRequest.get('productName')?.value ?? '';
    const productQuantity = this.addRequest.get('productQuantity')?.value ?? '';
    const productComment = this.addRequest.get('productComment')?.value ?? '';

    const newLine = new AddLineRequest(productName, productQuantity, productComment);

    // Créez un groupe de contrôles pour chaque ligne
    const lineGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      productName: [newLine.productName, Validators.required],
      productQuantity: [newLine.productQuantity, Validators.required],
      productComment: [newLine.productComment],
    });
    console.log('Ligne ajoutée:', lineGroup.value);

    this.lines.push(lineGroup);
    // On réinitialise les champs
    this.addRequest.get('productName')?.reset();
    this.addRequest.get('productQuantity')?.reset();
    this.addRequest.get('productComment')?.reset();
  }


  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (this.addRequest.valid) {
      const formulaireValue = this.addRequest.value;
      console.log('Formulaire valide, objet du formulaire:', formulaireValue);
    } else {
      console.log('Le formulaire est invalide, veuillez corriger les erreurs.');
    }
  }
  deleteLine(index: number) {
    this.lines.removeAt(index);
  }

}
```

```
Ligne ajoutée: 
Object { productName: "", productQuantity: "", productComment: "" }
​
productComment: ""
​
productName: ""
​
productQuantity: ""
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```